# Do "//" and "*" work differently in Mata?

Tags: stata

I just found that // and * work differently in Mata.
// works as expected, but * works inconsistently.

The following example shows that both // and * work as commenting commands.

```
. clear all
. mata
:         h=10
:         h
  10
: end

. 
. clear all
. mata
:         //h=10
:         h
                 <istmt>:  3499  h not found
r(3499);
: end

. 
. clear all

. mata
:         *h=10
                 <istmt>:  3499  h not found
r(3499);
:         h
                 <istmt>:  3499  h not found
r(3499);
: end
```

However, the following example shows that * does not work as a commenting command.

```
. clear all
. mata
:         h=10
:         st_numscalar("H",h)
: end
. di H
10

. 
. clear all
. mata
:         h=10
:         //st_numscalar("H",h)
: end
. di H
H not found
r(111);


. clear all
. mata
:         h=10
:         *st_numscalar("H",h)
                 <istmt>:  3257  nonpointer found where pointer required
r(3257);
: end
. di H
10
```

Comment: `*` does not prefix comments in Mata. This is documented at `help m2_comments`. Some reasons are that (1) physical lines are not so important in Mata and a command including a multiplication may continue on the next physical line and that (2) pointers are part of Mata.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!

Comment: The code  *h=10 does _not_ work as a comment. The error message shows that Mata looks beyond the `*`. It tries to make sense to the line as referring to a pointer, but cannot do so.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/mata/1619055-do-and-work-differently-in-mata It's always courteous to tell people about cross-posting.

Comment: Sure, I will do that later. I did not know that I need to tell the cross posting.

Comment: Just good forum etiquette in my view: People who might want to answer won't do that if there is a good answer elsewhere. People interested in the answer would want to see good answers elsewhere. But the expectation on Statalist is explicit in their FAQ,