# Is there a way to permanently store eststo?

Tags: stata

My Stata code is complicated that it has many `clear all` commands.

Is it possible to store `eststo` so that it does not wiped out by `clear` command?

I want those stored `eststo` to use later.

Comment: maybe `preserve` and `restore`?

Comment: `eststo` itself is code that doesn't go away. Otherwise this was cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1692902-is-there-a-way-to-permanently-store-eststo  and answered there, so should probably be deleted. You are most unlikely to get more or better answers here. (Telling people on SO about cross-posting is good practice too.)

Comment: See your previous thread at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68398387/do-and-work-differently-in-mata for the same advice about cross-posting.